# How do I go through a cursor to perform logic on multiple tables? (The table names are in the cursor)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor

I get the feeling this is pretty basic database work, but it isn't for me.  I'm trying to get a list of all of my tombstone tables from system tables and store the results in a cursor.  I'm then trying to perform some logic on each of those tables I'm having trouble doing so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the error I get:
Must declare the table variable "@tablename"

Here is the code:

```
declare tombstonetables cursor for 
(select name from sys.objects
where 
name like'%tombstone%'
and type = 'U'--for user_table
)

Print 'Begin purging tombstone tables'

declare @tablename varchar(250)
open tombstonetables

fetch next from tombstonetables into @tablename

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
select * from @tablename--real logic goes here later

fetch next from tombstonetables into @tablename

end
close tombstonetables

deallocate tombstonetables
```

Comment: I'm sorry if some of my language is syntactically off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to use [Dynamic SQL](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&expIds=17259,26474,27022,27692,27744&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=SQL+Server+dynamic+sql&cp=2&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=0c&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=b69933d19f024e3b)

Here is a reference to a simple walk through http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1160

You will probably need to make use of [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Here is a simple example of using Dynamic SQL with your example

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(100)

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
SET @DynamicSQL = 'select * from ' + @tablename --real logic goes here later
EXEC @DynamicSQL
fetch next from tombstonetables into @tablename

end
```

Comment: +1: Just to clarify for the op, the only way to use variable names as table names is to use dynamic sql.